# I get the following error when I use Perl interpreter with -e option

Tags: windows, perl

```
C:\Windows\system32>perl -e 'print "Hello World\n"'
Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.
```

Answer (score 4):

On MSWin, single quotes behave differently to *nix shells. You need double quotes instead, and for the inside, use the `qq` operator.

```
perl -e "print qq(Hello World\n)"
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. Why the qq?

Comment: To avoid the need to escape the nested double quotes.